# How do the chutes stay separate?

Tags: reentry, dragon, parachute

In the below picture the parachutes are spread out, but ordinarily drag would pull all the chutes to the same position directly behind the capsule. How is this spread achieved?

[image: SpaceX Crew Dragon Abort Test]

Comment: Agreed. Closing.

Comment: Rats! I was going to claim that they use special fabric that becomes charged from friction with the air so that they experience mutual electrostatic repulsion. (humor)